# ElasticSearch - Use minimum_should_match percentage in reference to the field total terms

Tags: database, elasticsearch, search, indexing, document

I'm trying to avoid false positive results when I'm querying for a phrase that is included inside other phrase.

My hope was that using the minimum_should_match parameter I was going to be able to set it to a minimum of terms according to the field's total.

```
{
   "match": {
       "notices.title": {
           "query": "Juan Pedro",
           "minimum_should_match": "-1"
        }
   }
}
```

The expected result was to match the **A.title** = "Dr. Juan Pedro" but **not** **B.title** = "Dr. Juan Pedro Pan". As you can see, according to the total amount of terms in A, the query is matching -1, and on B is -2.

I've already read the documentation and know that the parameter is to calculate the minimum required over the total amount of clauses in the query, but i'm hoping there's a way to do this in reference to the total terms of the field.

Any ideas? Thanks!

**Update**

Following the solution stated by @PrernaGupta I've ended up with a mix with matchphrase in order to avoid having to create the variable amount of match terms in the query.
Then I've used the amount of tokens in the string +1 to compare to the **title.length** field created.
This seems to be working. Let me know if you believe that it could produce any other error that I'm not seeing.

```
"bool": {
    "must": [
         {
           "match_phrase": {
                 "notices.title": {
                     "query": "Juan Pedro"
                  }
            }
          },
          {
            "term": {
                "notices.title.length": 3
             }
          }
     ]
}
```

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`token_count`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/token-count.html) field data type to achieve your minimum_should_match criteria.

### Mapping :

```
"mappings": {
            "properties": {
                "notices": {
                    "properties": {
                        "title": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "fields": {
                                "length": {
                                    "type": "token_count",
                                    "analyzer": "whitespace"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

### Indexed Data :

```
{"notices.title": "Dr. Juan Pedro"}
{"notices.title": "Dr. Juan Pedro Pan"}
{"notices.title": "Dr. Juan abc"}
```

### Search query :

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "notices.title": "Juan"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "notices.title": "Pedro"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "term": {
                        "notices.title.length": 3
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

### Search Result :

```
"hits": [
            {
                "_index": "notice",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 1.6292782,
                "_source": {
                    "notices.title": "Dr. Juan Pedro"
                }
            }
        ]
```

Here you can edit `notices.title.length` value with total number of terms that you want including "Juan" and "Pedro".

Comment: @Joaquin Ormachea Does this resolve your issue or were you looking for something else ?

Comment: @Joaquin Ormachea, if you were able to resolve the issue can you please accept and upvote my answer.

Answer (score -1):

you maby use must and must_not

"minimum_should_match": "-1" options  is "Juan" OR "Pedro" match